# Pscp freeze after connecting to server - while copying the file from windows to linux via cmd

Tags: linux, command-line, windows, putty, pscp

I am trying both **pscp.exe** and **winscp.exe** command line to copy a single file from **Windows 7** machine to **Linux (Deb)** machine but getting an below error.

**PuTTY Error**

```
pscp.exe -2 -v -sftp -pw password putty.chm admin@10.99.180.1:/base/data/backup/

Looking up host "10.99.180.1"
Connecting to 10.99.180.1 port 22
We claim version: SSH-2.0-PuTTY_Release_0.67
Server version: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.7
Using SSH protocol version 2
Doing Diffie-Hellman group exchange
Doing Diffie-Hellman key exchange with hash SHA-256
Host key fingerprint is:
ssh-rsa 2048 72:6c:f4:f6:e2:cb:bf:c2:89:e4:c5:8b:12:a3:e4:52
Initialised AES-256 SDCTR client->server encryption
Initialised HMAC-SHA-256 client->server MAC algorithm
Initialised AES-256 SDCTR server->client encryption
Initialised HMAC-SHA-256 server->client MAC algorithm
Using username "admin".
Attempting keyboard-interactive authentication
Server refused keyboard-interactive authentication
Sent password
Access granted
Opening session as main channel
Opened main channel
Started a shell/command
Using SFTP
Connected to 10.99.180.1
Server sent command exit status 0
Fatal: Received unexpected end-of-file from server
```

**PuTTY Freeze**

```
pscp.exe -2 -v -sftp -pw password putty.chm admin@10.99.180.1:/base/data/backup
Looking up host "10.99.180.1"
Connecting to 10.99.180.1 port 22
We claim version: SSH-2.0-PuTTY_Release_0.67
Server version: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.7
Using SSH protocol version 2
Doing Diffie-Hellman group exchange
Doing Diffie-Hellman key exchange with hash SHA-256
Host key fingerprint is:
ssh-rsa 2048 72:6c:f4:f6:e2:cb:bf:c2:89:e4:c5:8b:12:a3:e4:52
Initialised AES-256 SDCTR client->server encryption
Initialised HMAC-SHA-256 client->server MAC algorithm
Initialised AES-256 SDCTR server->client encryption
Initialised HMAC-SHA-256 server->client MAC algorithm
Using username "admin".
Attempting keyboard-interactive authentication
Server refused keyboard-interactive authentication
Sent password
Access granted
Opening session as main channel
Opened main channel
Started a shell/command
Using SFTP
Connected to 10.99.180.1
```

Then Ctrl+C to come out from the freeze.

**WinSCP Error**

```
WinSCP.com /command "option confirm off" "open admin:password@10.99.180.1" "put test.txt /base/data/backup/" "exit"
confirm off
Searching for host...
Connecting to host...
Authenticating...
Using username "admin".
Authenticating with pre-entered password.
Authenticated.
Starting the session...
Received too large (825372730 B) SFTP packet. Max supported packet size is 10240
00 B.
The error is typically caused by message printed from startup script (like .prof
ile). The message may start with "120:".
Cannot initialize SFTP protocol. Is the host running an SFTP server?
```

Answer (score 1):

After doing trial and error, got the answer:

```
winscp.com /command "open scp://uname:passwd@x.x.x.x" "put C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\%filename-case% /var/shared/data/dump/" "exit"
```

Here is the full batch script:

```
@echo off
cd\
color 0a
cls
title Copying File to Dump
set /p filename-case=Enter the name of the directory:
cls
cd C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP
winscp.com /command "open scp://uname:passwd@x.x.x.x" "put C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\%filename-case% /var/shared/data/dump/" "exit"
msg * Directory %filename-case% Copied OK !!!
exit
exit
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should use `scp` protocol instead `sftp`?

```
pscp.exe -v -scp -pw password putty.chm admin@10.99.180.1:/base/data/backup/
```